# Charging clients for creating business developer account Appstore and Googleplay

Tags: contracts

I'm facing a new problem. A client doesn't have any technical knowledge/doesn't want to deal with it.

They need apps on both GooglePlay and Apple Appstore, but they don't have developer accounts. I have been trough the process for myself some time ago, and it takes quite a lot of time, especially on the Appstore. How can I explain this to them & charge ?

For publishing, do you usually charge extra or do include this in some other fees without telling the client.

There's some other issue. How should I handle paying the Appstore/Google Play fees ? Should I pay with my own credit card, and then ask them to transfer the money back ?

I would apreciate any advice

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Charge him to creating and manage those accounts in both plataforms.

1. By *creating* the ones
2. By *monthly* or *yearly* manage ones

When I say *to manage*, I mean reply the mails from getting Play Store and Apple Store platforms. In fact, to talk with the app's users, just charge it as further service. That's at least what I'd do in that situation.

***Important**: regarding **"Should I pay with my own credit card"**, never buy with your one, ask to him for buying with the his one. Just guide he with that task of creating the accounts, it'll be only once and after it he'll provide to you the both accounts' information for accessing and management.*

Answer (score 1):

> How can I explain this to them & charge?

By explaining it to them? You're performing work on their behalf. If they want you to do this for them then you should be billing them for it. Tell them that this is billable work.

> Do you usually charge extra or do include this in some other fees
> without telling the client?

Why would you charge extra, as in over and above your normal fees? Why would you hide it? Explain to them that this is billable time and bill them what you would normally bill for billable time.

> Should I pay with my own credit card, and then ask them to transfer
> the money back?

Why would you set up these accounts with your payment information? This is for them. Use their payment information.